# How to use files from github to make loadable joomla 3.x extension

Tags: joomla3.0, genealogy

I still have a Joomla 2.5 site running because it uses a component called Joaktree which handles Genealogy data really well. In fact I haven't found anything better.

There is a beta version on Github at https://github.com/joaktree/J3.x. but the author hasn't supported it for some time so I guess he is ill.

I have two questions:
1. I don't know how to install the software from that location as installation files for Joomla are normally zipped in some format. Can someone advise?
2. I guess it is feasible for a non expert coder to slowly work through the errors and fix but does it make sense to do so?

Comment: Please revisit JoomlaStackExchange and tend to your abandoned question.  You have received two credible answers.  If neither solve your issue, please offer the volunteers feedback and clarify your question.  By awarding the best answer the green tick, the system will stop "bumping" your question.

Answer (score 0):

you may take content of https://github.com/joaktree/J3.x/tree/master/com_joaktree folder in repository and copy it over Joomla root. Then go to Joomla menu -> Extensions -> Manage -> Discover. Click Discover button in toolbar. It should find your extension. Select it and Click install and it will register it.

Same with modules and plugins.